# Oracle SPROC with TOP Parameter, ignore 0

Tags: oracle

I have this sproc that uses a parameter to work out how many records to take.
It looks like this:

```
procedure ReadStockToSync(P_CUR out sys_refcursor, P_TAKE integer) is

begin

      open P_CUR for
              select TOP (@P_TAKE)
```

What I want it to do, is ignore the `TOP` if `P_Take` is 0.
Does anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: There is no `TOP` in Oracle. And variables aren't prefixed with `@` in PL/SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd have two sql statements and decide which one to output based on the parameter, e.g.:

```
procedure readstocktosync (p_take in integer,
                           p_cur out sys_refcursor) is
begin
  if p_take = 0 then
     open p_cur for <your select query returning all rows>;
  else
     open p_cur for <your select query with the correct syntax to retrieve the "top" row(s)>;
  end if;
end readstocktosync;
```